# Difference between Activity ,Task and Log a Call in Salesforce?

Tags: tasks

I am a little confused regarding the differences between Activity Task and Log A Call.

Is Task comes under Activity? or vice-versa

Answer (score 2):

So, an **Activity** is a general term Salesforce uses to describe a record that is either a **Task** or an **Event**.

In Lightning Experience there's an Activity Timeline - this is essentially all Events or Tasks whose Due Date or End Date has passed.

**Log a Call** just creates a Task, but it gives you a chance to use a different layout for creating Tasks right after calls. So maybe your **New Task** tab gives 8 different fields to populate, and **Log a Call** only has 3 fields to populate, making it easier to quickly create Tasks with only the necessary information after a phone call.

Answer (score 2):

As stated above, a Salesforce Activity is a general term encompassing either a `Task` or an `Event`. Simple enough, right? But technically, there are actually 4 distinct Salesforce Activities.

1. `Event` to Salesforce is what we just consider a meeting. Like you put on your Outlook calendar. It has a date, start time and end time. And it is usually logged in Salesforce prior to its occurrence, and then Salesforce considers it 'completed' at the start time of the meeting. (a little odd, perhaps, as its not really 'completed' until the end time, but we quibble).

`Task` to Salesforce can be one of three things:

2. `Log a Call`

   - `Log a Call` is a great feature for sales people to use. It represents any interaction with a prospect or a customer - not necessarily a phone call - that has already happened
3. `New Task`

   - `New Task` is something that you, or someone else you designate, is going to do at some date in the future. It could be a task to call a prospect to follow up, or send a proposal, or send a Thank You or a reminder notice. I like to think of Tasks as my yellow sticky note reminders.
4. `email`

   - well, you should know what that is.  But like the others, Salesforce thinks of emails also in the broader category of "Tasks".

So the biggest difference between `Log a Call` and `New Task`, is that

- `Log a Call` represents something that already happened
- `New Task` is something that you are going to do in the future